# How to launch flow in full screen using quick action?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-experience, quickaction

I have added quick action on the record page. Using this quick action I'm launching the Screen flow, which contains the data table, but this screen is not taking the full space of the screen. It is displayed in a small modal, can we launch in a larger size modal or can we change the size of the modal?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question [Full Screen Quick Action - Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346746/full-screen-quick-action-lightning-component?rq=1)